# Provide an interface between the web browser and a Java application

Tags: java, php, javascript, xml, grails

Which language/tool do I use to provide an interface between the web browser and a Java application?

My task is create a web page and provide a feature which will enable results to be uploaded as XML files to dynamically update the page.

I have been instructed to use languages such as Java, Javascript(JQuery), Ruby, Grails, PHP etc.

So I have so far written some java classes that will process the XML files but I am running this application from the command line. I DO also understand how to display the XML on the web browser using XSLT.

My problem is, that I have only ever written desktop applications... I don't know what tools to use to provide an interface between my java back-end and the web front-end or how to (for lack of another method) invoke the JVM from the browser.

How do I send uploaded XML files to my java classes and get the XML results back? Can anyone shed some light into which tools I should use and the network packages (if needed) I need to import in Java? (note: this only needs to be run locally)

Feel free to make edits to tags/title and question if necessary.

Comment: That's what Servlets are for: they plug into a web server (like Tomcat or Jetty), are invoked when a HTTP request comes in, execute whatever Java logic they want, and generate a response. Google about them,you'll find plenty of tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working in `java` and i feel that `servlet-jsp` are the best option
 to full fill your requirement.